# Howto get @Service instance in Spring programatically

Tags: java, spring, facescontext

I need to implement `javax.faces.convert.Converter` to convert String-to-Object and Object-to-String.

To do so, I have defined specific services (`@Service`), but I do not know how to get an instance.

I have tried to use `@Autowired` and `@Component` to get instance, but Spring is ignoring.

Is it possible to get `@Service` instance from `FacesContext`?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/current/spring-framework-reference/html/web-integration.html

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible. Spring annotations are useless if it didn't configure to use them in your applications.

First You should get the application context like this

```
ApplicationContext ctx = FacesContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
```

Then use this context to get instance of the component.

```
YourService custB = (YourService )ctx.getBean("yourService");
```

Comment: It's certainly not impossible. Even if not the best option, I expect `@Configurable` could be made to work.

Comment: @chrylis I don't understand what are you saying could you elaborate it?